# Spock failed to discover tests when method call used in where clause

Tags: groovy, junit, spock

In Spock when I run:

```
@Unroll
def "max of #a and #b gives #c"() {
    expect:
    Math.max(a, b) == c
    where:
    [a, b, c] << [
            [1, 0, 1],
            [2, 2, 2],
            [4, 5, 5]
    ]

}
```

My tests pass. However when I try to extract the table into a static method and call the method in the where clause:

```
@Unroll
def "max of #a and #b gives #c"() {
    expect:
    Math.max(a, b) == c
    where:
    [a, b, c] << dataTable()

}

static def dataTable() {
    return [
            [1, 0, 1],
            [2, 2, 2],
            [4, 5, 5]
    ]
}
```

I get an error:

```
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'spock' failed to discover tests
Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: MethodSelector [className = 'specs.filters.FiltersPostSpec', methodName = 'max of #a and #b gives #c', methodParameterTypes = ''] resolution failed
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: specs/filters/FiltersPostSpec, method: $spock_feature_2_3prov0 signature: ()Ljava/lang/Object;) Illegal target of jump or branch
```

My versions are as follows:

```
<groovy.version>3.0.9</groovy.version>
<spock-core.version>2.1-groovy-3.0</spock-core.version>
<spock-reports.version>2.3.0-groovy-3.0</spock-reports.version>
```

Any ideas

A

Comment: I think you need to share a reproducer, it works in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_3_0&codez=eJxtTstqwzAQvOsrhvhiF2Ga0l5KAu0H9NT0FHxYy-tEVJGMpCSGkn-v7AY10C4D-5jZYfRhcD4iDE591obsrr4TQhkKAa_vAyvwGNl2AdOie60oamfxJZDq5cN6Z8w8d9xjcaARrkdBINuhaLHTJw4o1KKsrj9T8ZjM4nPe3yju6_RbkkRbYb2Gytx5z55_pdtJIqEarFboKNKGWsNlJWbF5aeFmFKqOdKN5CaA53j0Ftt8yPZLiXuJZSP_Ug8SE_6jHiWeEprMNNc4F_EN8w1VUQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading Leonard answer, i decided to play around with this. Changing groovy to 4.0.5 fixed the problem.

Comment: This answer is obviously wrong. Leonard's example in the GWC runs in all of Groovy 2.5, 3 and 4. So upgrading the Groovy version was not the solution here. Some other part of your Maven configuration must have been wrong.